# is there any way to use javax validation groups with BeanValidationBinder?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

On an entity with groupings in the constraints using javax validation groups

```
@Entity
public class Contact extends AbstractEntity {
    @Email
    @NotEmpty(groups=AdvanceInfo.class)
    private String email = "";
...
}
```

If BeanValidationBinder is used, constraints with groups are not taken into account,

```
    Binder<Contact> binder=new BeanValidationBinder<>(Contact.class);
    ...
    binder.bindInstanceFields(this);
```

I have read the Binder API and the only solution I have found is to do the validations manually, field by field.

Is there a way to use javax validation groups and the validation of a form automatically with bindInstanceFields from BeanValidationBinder?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/7032

TL;DR: Validation Groups are not supported.